# Como saber si una API me devuelve una respuesta con código de estado 200

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, test, jest

Básicamente estoy empezando con Jest y estoy queriendo saber con esta herramienta si una API me devuelve una respuesta con código de estado 200. He buscado muchas maneras de hacerlo en internet pero ninguna me resultó efectiva y no dejaban de saltarme errores.

¿Alguno me podría dar una mano con respecto a eso?

Por ejemplo, hacer un llamado a la API de Rick & Morty ya sea con Axios o Fetch y ver si devuelve un código de estado 200:

https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character

Intenté algo como esto:

Archivo "mock.js"

```
import axios from "axios";

class Movies {
    static all() {
        return axios.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character').then(resp => resp.data);
    }
}

export default Movies;
```

Archivo "mock.test.js"

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Movies from './mock.js';

jest.mock('axios');

test('should return a 200 status code', () => {
    expect(Movies.status).toBe(200)
})
```

Y me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: Response]

Comment: No soy experto en jest... Pero... Y donde estas llamando el método all? Ademas axios retorna una promesa, no veo que estes esperando que esa promesa se resuelva antes de revisar el valor del status

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es resolver la promesa y luego verificar si el status es 200

```
import Movies from 'path a la clase'

test('should return a 200 status code', async () => {
  const res = await Movies.all()
  expect(res.status).toBe(200)
})
```

Importante: esta pregunta esta con el tag de reactjs, este es un test que no pertenece al front-end